TLS Handshake fails on Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to connect from a Ubuntu 24.04 machine (actually a guest VM) to a SonicWall VPN using netExtender. My VPN connection fails after the Client Hello as the server responds with Handshake failure. I am attaching the screenshots for reference.
I maybe wrong, but the failure maybe because of TLS v1.0 in the record layer. This is strange since Ubuntu 24.04 release notes say that TLSv1.0 is forcibly disabled.
What is the problem and how do I fix it?



The hello is TLS1.2, and the client is willing to use TLS1.0 upto TLS1.3 the server responds with the handshake error, but not enough info on why. It may be a system time problem or no overlapping ciphersuites. This may help you troubleshoot https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/tls-handshake-failed/

The server is supporting TLS 1.0 only, with mostly old ciphersuites that no modern client accepts by default. The certificate is for 192.168.60.1 and it seems to be the management port, not the VPN.
https://testtls.com/96.90.193.97/4433

Thanks for the response. 192.168.0.1 is actually the Ubuntu client and the server is the SonicWall server. How can I fix the Ubuntu client to send a good request. Do I need to do any additional config like installing ceriticates, cipher suites, etc before initiating the VPN connection request. Where can I find more info about the same?

It's the sonic wall that needs fixing. The self signed cert is for 192.168.60.1, you can ignore certificate mismatched, but I would create a new cert to match your endpoint

Thanks again. Are you saying that I need to generate a new certificate for my Ubuntu client and give it to my network admin to install on the VPN/Firewall? Sorry if i sound clueless! :-(

No, it's the sonic wall that needs fixing, there the VPN needs a proper certificate, now it doesn't and it doesn't support anything than TLS1.0
